# .net How to make a search method non case sensitive?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern

In my MVC web application I am creating a search function where i need to compare a search string with objects in my product repository - But how do I make sure that the search is not case sensitive?
I can use ToLower() on my search string - but the repository?

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Search(string q, int page = 1)
 {
        string search = q.ToLower();
        int productCounter = repository.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(search) || p.Description.Contains(search)).Count();

            ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
                Products = repository.Products
                .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(search) || p.Description.Contains(search))
                .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = productCounter == 0 ? 0 : productCounter
                }
            };
        return View("List", model);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to entities case sensitive comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

Comment: looks covered in existing SO posts. was this tagged EF correctly ?

Answer (score 3):

You can replace this:

```
p.Name.Contains(search)
```

with this:

```
p.Name.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

Comment: really? IndexOf in EF queries. or Did you have an EF Query.ToList() and apply IndexOf on that ? HUGE difference.  I just ran a test on EF 6.1 to check. Bombed on my version. Docu suggests its not possible ...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550

Answer (score 3):

You can use IndexOf to get access to `IgnoreCase` in `In memory collections`.
You may be disappointed when you apply this to EF provider scenarios.
Is this correctly tagged EF ?

EF Provider specification does not use IndexOf.
For that matter the Contains(str,comparer) is also not supported.

[Supported Linq to Entities features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550)

If using SQLServer with EF the original issue is governed by the column collation property.  eg `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`   case insensitive latin.

If you have DB first, you control the collation sequence at DB level.

All explained here nicely ... [LINQ to Entities case sensitive comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

If using code first the DEFAULT sql server db collation is used.
more info on default collation [Set database collation in Entity Framework Code-First Initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054930/set-database-collation-in-entity-framework-code-first-initializer)

Comment: I have a EF repository making a IEnumerable of my products. When use IndexOf on that, it seems to work fine.

Comment: @MacLuc Ah, finally it appears that you're using the wrong approach. You're pulling everything into memory before filtering. That's highly inefficient as Phil explained in a comment. Your repository should return `IQueryable` and should be used internally.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Invariant Culture and enhance the query a bit by using Length as well:

```
 public ActionResult Search(string q, int page = 1)
    {
        string s;
        string search = q.ToUpperInvariant();
        int productCounter = repository.Products.Where(p => p.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(search) || p.Description.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(search)).Count();
        int searchlength = search.Length;
        ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
            .Where(p => (p.Name.Length >= searchlength && p.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(search)) || (p.Description.Length >= searchlength && p.Description.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(search)))
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = productCounter == 0 ? 0 : productCounter
            }
        };
        return View("List", model);
    }
```

Comment: If the length is already less than search then why would you do a search? In long strings it will filter faster.

Comment: Bad advice. `ToUpperInvariant` can't be translated into SQL, and it is a bad idea to convert database values before filtering. It disables indexes.

Comment: where did he mention in question he is searching database? Repository could be object based as well.

Comment: If that is the case then his query is already doing the job. Index of suggested above wont make any difference either.

Comment: The query is an expression tree that gets translated into SQL. The db engine does the real job.

Comment: .IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 seems like to be doing the job

Comment: With the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` part? How does EF translate that?

Comment: If you tagged this EF correctly, then I believe your query must be toList() and you apply the IndexOf, on the returned list. Was the filter applied at DB level.  careful ;-) Suggest SQL profile to be sure.  In fact post the SQL profile please.  That will confirm if the claim is correct