# Entity Framework seed -> SqlException: Resetting the connection results in a different state than the initial login. The login fails.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I get the following exception when running the seed method for Entity Framework. I only get the exception once, if I run the seed method a second time when the database has already been altered the code works. What can I do so that I don't have to run the code twice when creating the database the first time? I wan't to use seed and not alter the database using a custom migration.

> SqlException: Resetting the connection results in a different state
>   than the initial login. The login fails. Login failed for user ''.
>   Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill
>   state.

```
protected override void Seed(Repositories.EntityFramework.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, 
        string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [{0}] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS", context.Database.Connection.Database));

    //Exception here
    context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(
           role => role.Name,
           new ApplicationRole() { Name = RoleConstants.SystemAdministrator }
    );
}
```

If I don't use `TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction` I get the exception on `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`

> ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement
>   transaction.

Comment: Why are you altering the database in the seed method instead of a migration?

Comment: @S.C. I don't want to write any custom code in a migration, only have the auto generated. Someone should be able to delete all migrations, add a new migration and the database structure should look exactly the same.

Comment: That's a very limiting point of view. What about procedures, views, etc? If someone deletes all migrations and starts over your model will get out of sync with the `__MigrationHistory` table as well, so that goal only works for early development anyway. You're trying to both alter a database and add data to it. SQL does not allow both of those in the same transaction and EF tries to prevent that as well for good reasons. There are more maintainable built-in ways of accomplishing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054930/set-database-collation-in-entity-framework-code-first-initializer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set database collation in Entity Framework Code-First Initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054930/set-database-collation-in-entity-framework-code-first-initializer)

Comment: @S.C. We are not in production so we can still do this. After production is of course another question. How would you do it if not a migration or seed?

Comment: See the linked question for some options for doing that without custom migrations. None of them are as clean as a custom migration but depending on your priorities you might like one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this issue by using a plain ADO.Net connection, so the context's connection won't be reset:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = 
            string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [{0}] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS",
                context.Database.Connection.Database));
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```