# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException after CREATE/ALTER/PRINT

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

I'm coming from 2 other questions, and am trying to understand why this exception happens.

[Entity Framework seed -> SqlException: Resetting the connection results in a different state than the initial login. The login fails.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398421/entity-framework-seed-sqlexception-resetting-the-connection-)
results-in-a-dif

[What does "Resetting the connection" mean? System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721969/what-does-resetting-the-connection-mean-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0)

This code reproduces the exception.

```
string dbName = "TESTDB";
Run("master", $"CREATE DATABASE [{dbName}]");
Run(dbName, $"ALTER DATABASE [{dbName}] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS");
Run(dbName, "PRINT 'HELLO'");

void Run(string catalog, string script)
{
    var cnxStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = serverAndInstance,
        UserID = user,
        Password = password,
        InitialCatalog = catalog
    };

    using var cn = new SqlConnection(cnxStr.ToString());
    using var cm = cn.CreateCommand();
    cn.Open();
    cm.CommandText = script;
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The full stacktrace is

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Resetting the connection results in a different state than the initial login. The login fails.
Login failed for user 'user'.
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
...
```

If I change the first `Run(dbName...` to `Run("master"...` it runs fine.
So it's related to running `ALTER DATABASE` in the context of the same database

What does "Resetting the connection" mean?
Why is the session "in the kill state." ?
Should I avoid running "ALTER" statements inside the same database? Why?

Comment: I ran your code (with Integrated Security) and the exception happens when trying to print. I would assume printing is not part of your real code, is it? Did you test the user login?

Comment: The Net library has a connection pool and you have to dispose the pool, otherwise, you cannot change an object that is already  being used.

Comment: You might try `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();` after the alter database.

Comment: @jdweng could you explain better what object is being used?

Comment: @DanGuzman If I clear the pools after the ALTER the code runs without errors. I would still like to understand why.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: @jdweng connections are pooled by connection string. In this case the connection string is different. The pool shouldn't have tried to reuse the previous connection. If anything, this [should lead to too many connections and fragmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#pool-fragmentation-due-to-many-databases). Something fishy is going on here

Comment: It looks like running `ALTER DATABASE` with a connection string to that database is making the `SqlConnection` go to a "bad" state. As it is pooled, the next use of that connection fails.

Comment: When altering a database in SSMS is find I have to close SSMS and reopen before c# code recolonizes changes.  So I would assume you would have to do same when c# does same commands.

Comment: @jdweng any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Close/Open SMSS.  Have not found another way using SSMS.  Assume same with c#.

Comment: I may be missing something... I'm not using SSMS, only .NET. How can I do a similar operation to closing SSMS in C#?

Comment: I am not sure if you can run `PRINT` from ado.net. But, if you just want to print a message, why dont you use Console.WriteLine?

Comment: I dont want to print. It's just an example. Any query fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error "Resetting the connection results in a different state than the initial login. The login fails." is due to a [pooled connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) being reused after the database state change (database collation change). Below is what happens internally that leads to the error.

When this code runs:

```
Run(dbName, $"ALTER DATABASE [{dbName}] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS");
```

ADO.NET looks for an existing pooled connection by matching the connection string and security context. None is found because the connection string of the existing pooled connection (from the `CREATE DATABASE` query) is different (`master` database instead of `TESTDB`). ADO.NET then creates a new connection, which includes establishing a TCP/IP connection, authentication, and SQL Server session initialization. The `ALTER DATABASE` query is run on this new connection. The connection is added to the connection pool when it's disposed (goes out of the `using` scope).

Then this runs:

```
Run(dbName, "PRINT 'HELLO'");
```

ADO.NET finds the existing pooled `TESTDB` connection and uses that instead of instantiating a new connection. When the `PRINT` command is sent to SQL Server, the TDS request includes a reset connection flag to indicate it's a reused pooled connection. This causes SQL Server to internally invoke `sp_reset_connection` to do cleanup work like rollback uncommitted transactions, dropping temp tables, logout, login, etc.) as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120/what-does-exec-sp-reset-connection-mean-in-sql-server-profiler). However, `sp_reset_connection` cannot revert the connection back to the initial collation due to the database collation change, resulting in the login failure.

Below are some techniques to avoid the error. I suggest option 3.

1. invoke the static `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()` method after changing the collation
2. Specify `master` instead of `TESTDB` for the `ALTER DATABASE` command so that the existing 'master' pooled connection is reused instead of creating a new connection. The subsequent `PRINT` command will then create a new connection for `TESTDB` since one does not exist in the pool.
3. specify the collation on the `CREATE DATABASE` statement and remove the `ALTER DATABASE` command entirely