# Alter database collation in EF Core using migration scripts

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, collation

I am trying to change the collation of the database using the migration script.

This is the code from which I am trying to update the collation using EF Core.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        _ = migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS");

        _ = migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Employee",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                EmployeeName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false, collation: "LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI"),
            });
}
```

I get this error:

> Resetting the connection results in a different state than the initial login. The login fails.
> Login failed for user 'sa'.
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Could you check and specify if the "Resetting the connection" event happens because of .AlterDatabase, or .CreateTable?
Maybe none of the above. Does migration work without any of those two commands?

Comment: MsSql is the database

Comment: I have checked by removing the .AlterDatabase & it works fine without that line

Comment: Could you provide us with the generated migration code?
To quote MS: "While EF Core generally creates accurate migrations, you should always review the code and make sure it corresponds to the desired change; in some cases, it is even necessary to do so."

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server instance's `ERRORLOG` file around the time that this error happened? One possibility that comes to mind is that the database was not able to grow to record changes due to a lack of disk space. This happens frequently in Docker containers that are sharing storage allocations with the Docker subsystem instead of using their own storage volumes.

Comment: This happens when we create & alter the database in a single transaction. (I mean if we create the migration script for the first time it will create the database & alter the database at the same time) So, that is why it throws the error. If database is already created & if we run above migrations then it works fine.

Comment: @HardikParmar There you have it, you have found the solution. :)
Divide it into two separate migrations and there will be no problems!
Create separate migrations for each specific change, rather than combining multiple changes into a single migration.
P.S. I should turn this into an answer. Later...Will do... Promise... Until then, try this.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer**:
The error appears because the connection is reset and connection is in kill state, as the message says.
It is caused by a pooled connection being reused after the database state change (database collation change).
(see [stackoverflow.com/a/63766735/1555496](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63766735/1555496) for more details)

**Solution**:
Create another DbContext to use for database collation change, rather than combining into a single migration.

In this DbContext, set the pooling=false in connection string (and avoid pooling just for it).

1. Add additional connection string to appsettings.json for pooling=false

   "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity3;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
   "NoPoolingConnection": "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity3;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;pooling=false;"
   },
2. Create additional DbContext

   public class SchoolNoPoolingContext : DbContext
   { ...
3. Register additional DbContext in service in Startup.cs

   services.AddDbContext(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

   services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NoPoolingConnection")));

In your case, divide your migration script into two scripts, like this:

Migration script 1:

```
// Use for [DbContext(typeof(SchoolNoPoolingContext))]
//
// Change DB Collation:
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS");
}
```

Migration script 2:

```
// Use for [DbContext(typeof(SchoolContext))]
//
// Create Table ...
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Employee",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                EmployeeName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false, collation: "LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI"),
            });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't make any difference, the error occours next time a new SqlConnection attempts to connect from the same process. You need to reset the connection pool after changing the db collation, or create the connection with Catalog Name=master in the first place. It seems that EF Core does neither. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63766735/1555496 for more details.

Comment: @poizan42: You are linking to a good explanation. Pooling is causing the issue. However, I have managed to mitigate this by introducing another DbContext, which has pooling set to false. This DbContext is then used for ALTER DATABASE... Will add my example to my answer...