# Entity Framework using wrong string encoding?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

If I write a string to a SQL Server table using Entity Framework (migrated an existing database to EF), then measure the string length in SQL Server Management Studio, my string is way too long. It appears that the different collation types are adding a bunch of white space at the end of the string.

Do I have to set the collation type for EF explicitly? If so, is there a better method than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31119371/1634753)?

Got the default collation:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation') SQLServerCollation
```

result:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I measured the string like this (returns 51 characters, when the string is "Bill"):

```
SELECT 
    LEN(CONCAT(first_name, '!' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS))
FROM 
    [GreenCardSite].[dbo].[AppUser]
WHERE
    user_id = 16840
```

Note that the ! is added to the end of the string because by default SQL Server does not measure white space when calculating length. Further, when I ran this without specifying the collation I got an error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS" in the concat operation.

`AppUser` EF class:

```
[Table("AppUser")]
public partial class AppUser
{
    [Key]
    public int user_id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    .....
```

Comment: What is the column data type for `AppUser`?

Comment: Interesting. I don't know what's going on. Are you sure it's not related to the ANSI_PADDING setting instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: And what makes you think there isn't white space on the end of your column?

Comment: @DavidG, I added the partial class declaration above. And Im certain there is no white space because I updated the value explicitly using EF and hardcoded the string "Bill" before I ran my tests.

Comment: Note this has nothing to do with Entity Framework, what is the *underlying SQL type*?

Comment: @Ben I just checked and ANSI_PADDING is set to ON

Comment: @DavidG In sql server the type is char(50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is nothing to do with your collation. Your column type is a `CHAR(50)`. In a column of that type, the rest of the content of the field is padded out with spaces so instead of `Bill` you actually have `Bill____________________________________`.

So you either need to change the datatype to be `VARCHAR(50)` or you will need to trim the spaces:

```
SELECT len(concat(rtrim(first_name), '!'))
FROM [GreenCardSite].[dbo].[AppUser]
WHERE user_id = 16840
```